# Dynamic queue and async/await

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to wrap my head around how to properly write some code in C# that uses a queue.

- Queue holds some initial items
- Dequeue until queue drains and invoke async function
- The async function can enqueue new items
- Need to keep running until all tasks are finished and queue is drained

Here is some pseudo code that I wrote:

```
Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
static async Task SomeTask(item) {
    var newTask = await GenerateNewTask();
    if (newTask != null)
        queue.Enqueue(newTask);
}

static void Main() {
    while (queue.Count > 0) {
        SomeTask (queue.Dequeue());
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with how I'd write my Main function here. The queue will drain but new items are added, so that's not really working.

Comment: So after initial set of tasks executes some more tasks are queued which doesn't get get executed. Am I right?

Comment: You probably write the queue with await the same way you'd write it without await in a synchronous version.

Answer (score 0):

Try locking the queue when working with it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Queue<T>` type in .NET is not threadsafe, and is not the best option for a producer/consumer queue.

I recommend you consider [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) or [`BufferBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414.aspx).